# Creating log file in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am relatively new to both Angular 2 and typescript. I want to create a log file in angular 2. Can it be possible using angular 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that you will need a package like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

First, you need to install the package itself:
`npm install file-saver --save`

The definition files as well:
`npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev`

Then you create a method let say in your component:

**some.component.ts**

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'; // Don't forget to import the file-saver
...    
saveLogFile(): void {
    saveAs(new Blob([log], { type: "text" }), 'data.log');
}
```

Where the `[log]` is the content of your log file, `{ type: "text" }` this defines the type you wan't to save and `'data.log'` defines how you wan't to save the file (`filename.extension`).